# Could not initialize repository... Unknown repository format "null"; expected "0"

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I am getting this error when i try to run Maven Install my proejct, or run my application

```
 Could not initialize repository... Unknown repository format "null"; expected "0"
```

I have just import the project from repository and its start showing this error 
I've google but no Luck.

also here's an error in my application

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\wageeha junaid\git\Quran-Sementic-Search-Engine\qsse\target\javax.validation-validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar'  qsse        Build path  Build Path Problem



Could not initialize repository... (pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id- plugin:1.5:revision:default:generate-sources) pom.xml /qsse   line 315    Maven Build Problem
```

Any idea what could be the reason 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to do a mvn install on command instead from Eclipse...

Comment: can u give me an idea how to do that, coz i simply install maven from eclipse plugin , by going to eclipse/hep/install software.

Comment: do you have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each project you import into Eclipse, Eclipse makes some files on filesystem - `.project, .classpath`, a folder `.settings`, ... . It seems that Eclipse doesn't update these correctly.

The answer is to right-click on a project and pick `Maven/Update` Snapshots.

Comment: thanks, after right click then maven there are options of update configurations and update dependencies , tried both but no luck , any suggestion