# Could not complete Mojo execution... Could not initialize repository... Unknown repository format "1"; expected "0"

Tags: maven

i'm deploying with maven and got this issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.1:revision (default) on project notification-gateway-api: Could not complete Mojo execution... Could not initialize repository... Unknown repository format "1"; expected "0". -> [Help 1]
```

it's similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068789/could-not-initialize-repository-unknown-repository-format-null-expected-0) but it's doesn't help. it run ok on my local but not run on CI/CD system

Please help to advice

Comment: I would strongly recommend to upgrade that version because its of 2016....